# Criar um diretório protegido no storage do dispositivo

Tags: java, android

Através de uma aplicação é possível criar, editar e remover, tanto arquivos, quanto diretórios, porém sabemos que é necessário o usuário dar permissão de leitura e escrita dependendo a ocasião. Para que de fato essa permissão seja concedida, normalmente deve inserir uma tag `<users-permission />` no `<manifest></manifest>`, como exemplo *`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`* e *`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`*.

Veja abaixo um comando simples para criar um diretório:

```
File dir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), filename );
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
```

Depois de todo procedimento feito, inserindo documentos e imagens dentro desse diretório, ao acessar um gerenciador/galeria de arquivos, sendo ele nativo do smartphone ou não, o usuário consegue ver esses arquivos normalmente.

Tenho uma aplicação no qual gostaria de visualizar estes documentos somente dentro dele, portanto da forma como é hoje, os arquivos também podem ser visualizados através da galeria.

É possível criar um diretório protegido no *storage* do dispositivo? Existe alguma outra forma de resolver esse problema, para que o usuário não consiga vizualizar os arquivos fora da aplicação, ou que visualize somente através de uma senha?

Comment: Como você obtém o `path` que usa em  `new File(path)`?

Comment: @ramaral eu coloquei esse código somente como exemplo. Você acha que é relevante colocar na pergunta?!

Comment: É porque isso é que irá determinar se o directório é privado ou não. Vou colocar uma resposta.

Comment: Uma maneira simples é deixar o diretório com um ponto antes do nome, exemplo. ".AppX". Isso mantém o diretório oculto, e impede que a galeria e os exploradores nativos encontre o diretório ou os arquivos dentro. Somente alguns aplicativos que tem permissão de root e a opção de visualizar arquivos ocultos.

Comment: Por que está a usar [DIRECTORY_DCIM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_DCIM)? Não faz sentido já que ela se refere à pasta pai das pastas públicas.

Comment: @ramaral Eu tinha colocado apenas como exemplo por você ter cobrado. Na realidade estou criando um diretório com nome `apptal` dentro de `/mnt/sdcard/`. Então na realidade está ficando assim `/mnt/sdcard/apptal`

Comment: Não deve usar caminhos escritos na mão. Já tentou usar `getExternalFilesDir()` com por exemplo **DIRECTORY_PICTURES**? É que assim verificava se o que eu digo na resposta se confirma e que a documentação está certa(nem sempre está).

Answer (score 3):

OS dispositivos Android dispõem de duas áreas de armazenamento de arquivos: interna(*internal storage*) e externa(*external storage*).

Arquivos criados na área interna são sempre privados, apenas a aplicação que os criou pode acedê-los.
Use `getFilesDir()` para obter o caminho.

Em relação aos arquivos criados na área externa depende do tipo área externa e do modo como o caminho é obtido.

Alguns dispositivos usam parte da memória interna como *external storage*, emulando um *sdcard*. Mesmo não tendo um *sdcard* ela é apresentada à API como se fosse.

Assim, em relação à *external storage*, verifica-se o seguinte:

- *external storage* no *sdcard*:

  - Os arquivos são públicos e aplicações com permissões READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE e WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE podem acedê-los.
  - Se o caminho for obtido por `getExternalFilesDir()` não são visíveis pela galeria e serão eliminados quando a aplicação é desinstalada.
- *external storage* emulado:

  - Os arquivos são privados se o caminho for obtido por `getExternalFilesDir()`.


    Nota: Pelo menos é o que entendo da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29):

    > If a shared storage device is emulated (as determined by     Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(File)), it's contents are backed by a private user data partition, which means there is little benefit to storing data here instead of the private directories returned by getFilesDir(), etc.

> É possível criar um diretório protegido no storage do dispositivo?

Uma solução é encriptar os arquivos usando as classes [Cipher](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher), [CipherOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream) e [CipherInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream).

Comment: @Viana Parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.